# Trade-offs/benefits of Controlling LabView Vi's with Active X vs. Open source Python automation package?

Tags: python, activex, labview

What are the benefits/trade-offs to controlling LabView vi's via Active X (as depicted here: https://forums.ni.com/t5/Example-Programs/Controlling-a-VI-using-Python-using-LabVIEW/tac-p/3685228) vs. this opensource tool developed by NI employees (https://github.com/ni/python_labview_automation)?